# Access Denied with CURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, cookies, request, header

I'm trying to access this website natura.com.br to get info about some products, I'm trying to make a request the same way I do in the browser but I receive Access denied.

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.natura.com.br/";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
   "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
   "Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
   "Connection: keep-alive",
   "Cookie: dtPC=11$302937546_809h-vKVNUNMUJAHDKTQPPAHFQIMSCQPPRKILC-0e0; rxvt=1625712010903|1625710210903; _abck=141C18ABCC9C79DFA1F4D45EF108501A~-1~YAAQk9j2SGYWZX56AQAAtC1zgwbF2BpCRBBWxNKDpMPWjPEYtw7XLvfB2g+dxkZSpfXBRCTvbE4fZTzGxjqtGVa7tZqz9pWp/hYSf65phFg2VW06IioCwpy7tox8su7QlWIt3eZUeTFIJ5S7nRtSv3Te859lzghM7a2lLnZOjpjS5eYLrJzYzyKFsRdc8Kpgj+sGCZA9iKiMvfqtJlI5e+90UfUDDzTQB2sV2U5i2yavjB+GsgBZ1qcKIfmo41PYfXtS8efG+3C4F4cw3sePIjj4vQIex1pQdg3twIbyqAMsEClNaqbGJ29NVu/orK7dAJ7rteSqWvyMuMu9MCltlPoYaYYi/O0Uzv18AiK9hSMYYWod7U/IqUkfE/touhQz6OT0S2KPjG0wJVJ8dghA8LdDJFH4+Y3YX4+oDw==~0~-1~-1; dtCookie=v_4_srv_11_sn_44IDRCETVPHGS7OCQ5F7DV8IS6T6HDI3_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3A2a1999229615da92_1_app-3A58ea22250e34b990_1_rcs-3Acss_0; rxVisitor=1625332161003TGNBC4CH08VFEACK6NT19CQ14GERSQEA; dtSa=-; dtLatC=6; RT="z=1&dm=www.natura.com.br&si=a6979d10-a558-4bb3-a962-ccb19999271b&ss=kqu5jycl&sl=0&tt=0"; JSESSIONID=IUGNrH_B8h7DHZlVAsWr38FYiZq_I13dabE1sdnURzTRvdlsps50!-405357702; verifyFirstRequest=true; ORDER_ID=%3B%20; ORDER_NUMBER=%3B%20; X-Oracle-BMC-LBS-Route=93a9c3aed1d29d32ea0391633407edd696daed8327da03a11a2ff120e313e9b656c62fd8a7c42ae86da5fb4c73ec2333f092dbf8c9611add8055dec1; undefined; GTMUtmTimestamp=1625702943894; GTMCampaignReferrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F; GTMCampaignLP=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.natura.com.br%2Fp%2Fdesodorante-Col%25C3%25B4nia-kaiak-urbe-masculino-100ml%2F34075%3Futm_content%3DSP_Resp_MCKaiak_2020_Kaiak_Urbe%26cnddefault%3Dtrue%26gclid%3DEAIaIQobChMIxrmerJfS8QIV7R-tBh01uwM5EAAYASAAEgIZU_D_BwE; _gcl_au=1.1.467484977.1625332166; _ga_15QCH7XEDY=GS1.1.1625874531.3.0.1625874531.60; _ga=GA1.3.1744316957.1625332166; GTMBrowserSessionEntranceTimestamp=1625332166546; GTMBrowserSessionEntranceLP=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.natura.com.br%2Facesso-consultor; GTMBrowserSessionEntranceReferrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F; GTMLastEntranceTimestamp=1625702945066; GTMLastEntranceLP=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.natura.com.br%2Fp%2Fdesodorante-Col%25C3%25B4nia-kaiak-urbe-masculino-100ml%2F34075%3Futm_content%3DSP_Resp_MCKaiak_2020_Kaiak_Urbe%26cnddefault%3Dtrue%26gclid%3DEAIaIQobChMIxrmerJfS8QIV7R-tBh01uwM5EAAYASAAEgIZU_D_BwE; GTMLastEntranceReferrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F; _fbp=fb.2.1625332167173.86579534; GTMUtmSource=google; GTMUtmMedium=cpc; GTMUtmCampaign=auto; GTMGclid=EAIaIQobChMIxrmerJfS8QIV7R-tBh01uwM5EAAYASAAEgIZU_D_BwE; _gcl_aw=GCL.1625702944.EAIaIQobChMIxrmerJfS8QIV7R-tBh01uwM5EAAYASAAEgIZU_D_BwE; _ttgclid=EAIaIQobChMIxrmerJfS8QIV7R-tBh01uwM5EAAYASAAEgIZU_D_BwE; _ttgclid=EAIaIQobChMIxrmerJfS8QIV7R-tBh01uwM5EAAYASAAEgIZU_D_BwE; __bid=4dbbd24a-fc0e-42aa-a664-43c865cae2ef; _gac_UA-35236522-3=1.1625703004.EAIaIQobChMIxrmerJfS8QIV7R-tBh01uwM5EAAYASAAEgIZU_D_BwE; cto_bundle=qVL1jF8yb3h2cW01cmFaUjF5S2VnMkdGcDEyNHdrWWM3ZXpZcFFIMkowdmZqOFZpNTE3VGIlMkJibkZZZXpMJTJGYXBqRElFT0FwdFRia3ZwQ1JZSzZ2ZEx1RSUyQnBXUW54MmM1S3UlMkY3WjlqenBXU1dDZFlRaTYlMkZucVdPM2c5MTJUcERYc2pLcEdyeURWQU9ieDhmaTR1WGJoN1FhaHR4Nm5MZWdJUUNmZUI0MkdNYk50VXpFRGg0Z2hUSlNxS25xZGFNVjJZTGpC; GTMVisitSession=1625702947208; GTMVisitPermanent=1625702947208; _uetvid=b67fe410df8011eb85947b37dce069f8; smeventsclear_d13b2682b72e42cc9203ee1f0a20b68d=true; personNumber=141692103; smCloseBounce=true",
   "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

I get this HEADER when I do the request

```
"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Server: AkamaiGHost Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 271 Cache-Control: max-age=1800 Expires: Sat, 10 Jul 2021 21:35:46 GMT Date: Sat, 10 Jul 2021 21:05:46 GMT Connection: close Server-Timing: cdn-cache; desc=HIT Server-Timing: edge; dur=1 Timing-Allow-Origin: true Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true Access-Control-Allow-Headers: * Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: see how the colours of the font in your code changes for `$302937546_809h` and the same for the other one where you're using `"`? It would be borking the cookie and the server or IDS is perhaps not liking it, you should try with single quotes, additionally, things like JSESSIONID wont persist forever, so is most likely going to break at some point

Comment: You can remove the `cookie` part entirely, you should still be able to get the page without it, but if you really need it, change from double quotes to single quotes. Since you have double quotes in the header string it terminates that value early and expects a new array value after but the parser sees a `z` instead causing a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, within "" PHP tries to convert variables to strings. So

```
$foo = "Hello, ";
echo "$foo World" . PHP_EOL;
```

would output

> Hello, World

You are using "" and have the $-sign in your cookie (not to mention the fact that the cookie-string itself contains the "-sign). So PHP is not sending that "as-is" in the cookie but instead trying to find that variable and turn it into a string. If you don't want this behavior use single quotes ' instead.
So that could be your issue as long as the information in the cookie is valid and should allow you access.

Besides this it is hard to know what happens in the backend of **natura.com.br** to block your access. It could be any number of things. Do you need to login, do you have a valid session etc.

Instead of working with curl directly you could use [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) which is a great PHP based HTTP-Client that simplifies a lot of stuff. It can keep track of cookies and append them automatically etc.